# IIS asp.net C# API Post Method error "'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'"

Tags: c#, api, iis, gupshup

I have via gupshup created a viber bot. I run my WebForm application with IIS server in win 10. I tried to send a message to my viberbot via api post method but c# strangle me.(I tested url and parameters with success)

here is my code :

```
protected void viber_msg(String viberid, String strmsg)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/bot/mybotname/msg?apikey=mykey");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

   
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "context={'botname':'mybotname','channeltype':'viber','contextid':'viberid','contexttype':'p2p'}&message="+strmsg;
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
    
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viber_msg("viberuserID", "This is a message");
}
```

The error I am getting is "`System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'`"
Also tried with POSTMAN and getting `"message": "Invalid authentication credentials"`
Thnx in advance...

Comment: I thing you have two issues 1) The c# code 2) The Postman where key is wrong. 
 apikey=mykey  First get Postman working which is easier than c#.  When a request is made with https TLS is used for authentication.   The c# is failing due to the TLS version being used.  Postman is passing the TLS authentication but failing because the id is wrong.

Comment: My apikey is OK. I use the same url in java programm(eclipse). the context also right.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request between eclipse and Postman to see why Postman it is failing.  Also compare the TLS version in eclipse and c#  to see the differences in the tLS version.  When was the last time you used the eclipse application?  TLS 1.0/1.1 is no longer functional and old code may not work.

Comment: I succed to post with postman just adding 2 new parameters userId and password for my acount to gupshup. I tried to to add in C# but failed. "https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/bot/botname/msg?apikey=myapikye&userId=myuserid&password=mypassword"

Comment: In c# before your WebRequest add : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12  If Tls12 doesn't work then try Tls13.

Comment: thnx, With tls12 same error. tls13 doesnt exist. only tls, tls11, tls 12

Comment: Your version of VS is old.  So you have to use a number : (System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol)12288  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I tried ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288; (Failed with same error. ) and 3072(Error message System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.'). From fiddler with postman whice succed (Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)) and with VS the  missing from fiddler report a lot of things.

Comment: You need to compare the headers in first request of working and non working with fiddler. make c# headers look like working.  You should be using TLS 1.2 like the working app.  The default headers in c# are not the same as Postman.  Refuse could be the User Agent (which is the type of browser).  Some server refuse to accept request from certain browsers.  So yo may need to change the User Agent : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: SOLUTION-->>Via postman I generate code for C#(THERE IS OPTION).  using RestSharp; this is a good library. thnx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void viber_msg(String viberid, String message)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/bot/mybot/msg?apikey=myapikey");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("context", "{\"botname\": \"mybot\",\"channeltype\" :\"viber\",\"contextid\": \""+viberid+"\",\"contexttype\": \"p2p\"}");
    request.AddParameter("message", message);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
} 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viber_msg("viberid", "message");
}
```

}

RestSharp Library!!!

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue